# update value of key in json php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have this json

```
[{"id":"Horario","text":"Horario","answer":null},{"id":"Name","text":"Nome","answer":"teste"},{"id":"Phone","text":"Telefone","answer":"91"},{"id":"Email","text":"Email","answer":"teste@hotmail.com"},{"id":"Insc1","text":"Insc1","answer":"albano"},{"id":"Insc2","text":"Insc2","answer":"jorge"},{"id":"Insc3","text":"Insc3","answer":""}]
```

and I want to update answer value for "id" Horario with the value I'm getting according to a radiobutton is selected.

I want something like this but I can't figure why is passing null to the specific "id" Horario,

```
    foreach($legend as $obj){
         if($obj->id == 'Horario')  
            $obj->answer=$option;
    }
```

--- all my code

```
$legend = json_decode($request->input('quiz-legend'));  
$option=Input::get('qOp');

$answers = [];
$answersToTable = [];

foreach ($legend as $q) {
    array_push($answers, array(
        'id' => $q->id,
        'text' => $q->text,
        'answer' => $request->input('q'.$q->id)
    ));
}

foreach($legend as $obj){
    if($obj->id === 'Horario')
        $obj->answer=$option;
}

var_dump($option);
var_dump($answers);
```

So my var_dump returns result for $option = 2 but in my answer is null...

```
:\xampp\htdocs\LactInfo\app\Http\Controllers\InquiryController.php:178:string '2' (length=1)
D:\xampp\htdocs\LactInfo\app\Http\Controllers\InquiryController.php:179:
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Horario' (length=7)
      'text' => string 'Horario' (length=7)
      'answer' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Name' (length=4)
      'text' => string 'Nome' (length=4)
      'answer' => string 'teste' (length=22)
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Phone' (length=5)
      'text' => string 'Telefone' (length=8)
      'answer' => string '91' (length=9)
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Email' (length=5)
      'text' => string 'Email' (length=5)
      'answer' => string teste@hotmail.com' (length=22)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Insc1' (length=5)
      'text' => string 'Insc1' (length=5)
      'answer' => string 'albano' (length=6)
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Insc2' (length=5)
      'text' => string 'Insc2' (length=5)
      'answer' => string 'jorge' (length=5)
  6 => 
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string 'Insc3' (length=5)
      'text' => string 'Insc3' (length=5)
      'answer' => string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, you probably meant to use `==` or `===` which are comparisons.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I've updated my answer

Comment: What's the problem then?

Comment: My code dont do anything.. answer in object with "id" Horario remains "null", and $option have value

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/WmeMf

Comment: when I make a print_r the value stays null.

Comment: What about when using `var_dump` instead of `print_r`? What about `var_dump($option)`?

Comment: I've updated my answer according with your hints. Option return 2

Comment: Wait, what? I didn't notice you were dumping out `$answers` and not `$legend`. Your second loop doesn't touch `$answers` so why do you expect it to modify it? IF you var_dump($legend) you'll see that answer has changed. If you don't care about changing $legend, why don't you just change the `answer` index in your first loop? E.g. `'answer' => ($q->id === 'Horario') ? $option : $request->input('q'.$q->id)` or similar.

Comment: Yes that worked! Thanks